# Combining multiple IF Formulas, with different "true"/"false" values

Tags: excel

```
IF(OR(T103="YesNoNo",T103="YesNoYes"),MIN(G14,D7),G15)
IF(OR(T103="YesYesYes",T105="YesYes"),MIN(G15,D7),G14)
IF(T105="YesNo",G15,IF(T103="YesYesNo",G15,T100))
```

I can get these 3 IF formulas to work separately; but when I try to combine them I am getting stuck. I need to somehow combine them so that one cell will return a certain value based on the 3 rules above.

I do not want to use the VBA option.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by combine the 3 rules?

Comment: If you break down each of the IF formulas above I actually have 6 IF formulas. I need all 6 IF statements combined so that depending on what the user selects in one (or 2, or 3) cells; it will return the correct value to the cell that I am setting up the formula in. (ie: I have 3 cells that the user will enter a percentage into. I have 3 cells that the user answers Yes/No. I have 6 scenarios that I need to have one of the percentage values (or the lesser of 2 of the percentages) returned based on the Yes/No answers). I did set up CONCATENATE rules (in another cell) for the YesNo combinations.

Comment: I think people will struggle to answer this as it stands because the logic seems to contradict itself - you might need to set up a matrix to work out what inputs go with what outputs

Comment: If the user enters 4%,5%,13%. For the first IF formula: If user answers Yes, No,and No or Yes,No, and Yes (to specific questions); the formula with provide the lesser of 5% or 13% if "true" other wise it will return 4% if "false"

Comment: I feel like the issue I am having when trying to combine, is that my "false" value is different on each of the 3 formulas. On all the examples I have seen for "nesting" IF formulas, the "false" value is the same for all of the nested IF Formulas. In my example they are different(ie: on the first formula "false" value is G15, second has G14, 3rd has T100)